# hyperledger sawtooth submit transaction error "Tried to get unauthorized address" with status invalid

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

the same question has been asked in here -> [Sawtooth Transaction error: "Tried to set unauthorized address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663482/sawtooth-transaction-error-tried-to-set-unauthorized-address) and I tried that answer. But that answer didn't work for me.

i'm using hyperleder sawtooth docker compose to start my services. I'm doing exactly the same thing in this documentation which provided by hyperledger-sawtooth -> https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/_autogen/sdk_submit_tutorial_js.html#create-the-transaction-header

My payload is

```
const payload = {
    Verb: 'set',
    Name: 'test',
    Value: 32
}
```

My transaction header is

```
const transactionHeaderBytes = protobuf.TransactionHeader.encode({
    familyName: 'intkey',
    familyVersion: '1.0',
    inputs: ['1cf1266e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7'],
    outputs: ['1cf1266e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7'],
    nonce: (Math.random() * 10 ** 18).toString(36),
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    batcherPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    dependencies: [],
    payloadSha512: createHash('sha512').update(payloadBytes).digest('hex')
}).finish()
```

Then i did the same process like in the documentation and when i check the status of that transaction, it gives me below response.

[image]

Then i check the log of the sawtooth server and it looked like below.

[image]

Then after seeing an answer the same question on here ([Sawtooth Transaction error: "Tried to set unauthorized address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663482/sawtooth-transaction-error-tried-to-set-unauthorized-address)), I tried `inputs` and `outputs` arrays as empty arrays like []. But response was same.

My docker-compose file contains below containers

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sawtooth Transaction error: "Tried to set unauthorized address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663482/sawtooth-transaction-error-tried-to-set-unauthorized-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting empty arrays like [] to `inputs` and `outputs` is not an option. This would mean you're not letting any of the address read and write possible through your transaction processor. You can however set the partial address in `inputs` and `outputs`. For example, you can set `1cf126` for both `inputs` and `outputs` and your code will start working.

Setting partial address would enable your TP to read and/or write any of the leaf node under the sub-tree your address points to. Refer to the https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/architecture/global_state.html?#radix-merkle-tree-overview section to understand how that works.

The example given in the documentation is for the `intkey` transaction family and the input is

```
const payload = {
    Verb: 'set',
    Name: 'foo',
    Value: 32
}
```

But if you would like to set `test` instead of `foo` then you will have to calculate the address for it and place it in `inputs` and `outputs`. Note address calculation is something you keep consistent across a client and a TP for particular Transaction Family. The way `intkey` does it is by concatenating two of the following

1. Sha512(`intkey`) - first 6 characters in hex representation
2. Sha512(`foo`) - Rest of the characters from 64th index

for `foo`.

Ref: https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-rust/blob/190861a14046122ce6ecd684908c3d7a877e26ca/examples/intkey_rust/src/handler.rs#L175

In case of `test` this would be concatenation of

1. Sha512(`intkey`) - first 6 characters in hex representation
2. Sha512(`test`) - Rest of the characters from 64th index

Hope this clarifies. Also, please refer to the Merkle-Radix definition above, it has detailed information on how address can be calculated. It is upto the implementer of Transaction Family.